# How do you make Capybara find an HTML comment?

Tags: rspec, capybara

I would like my test to pick up an HTML **comment** that is in a block of HTML I want to test however when buiding a Capybara node using SimpleNode it seems to be erase all HTML comments.

e.g.

```
html = "<div>before <!– check –> after</div>"
node = Capybara::Node::Simple.new(html)
node.native.to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" 
\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body>
<div>before  after</div></body></html>\n"
```

The text sections, `before` and `after` have been totally removed in the HTML.

How can I preserve them so they can be detected in tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML comments require two `-` after the <! - what you have is just being parsed as an invalid element and discarded.

```
html = "<div>before <!-- check --> after</div>"
node = Capybara::Node::Simple.new(html)
node.native.to_html
=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><div>before <!-- check --> after</div></body></html>\n"
```

Comment: Brilliant - well spotted 